Why is the centroid at this point in polar coordinates?
Prove that for a plane figure:
$0\leq\alpha\leq\varphi\leq\beta\leq\pi$ ,  $0\leq r\leq r\left( \varphi \right)$  ;  ($ \varphi$ and $r$ are polar coordinates)
the volume of the solid of revolution formed by rotating around the polar axis is equal to $V=\frac{2\pi}{3}\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}r^{3}\left( \varphi \right)\sin\varphi\mathrm d\varphi$
My solution:
The infinitesimal area element $\mathrm dA=r\mathrm dr\mathrm d \varphi$ , when rotated around the polar axis, forms an infinitesimal toroidal volume element
$\mathrm dV=2\pi r \sin \varphi \mathrm dA=2\pi r^{2}\sin\varphi\mathrm dr\mathrm d\varphi$
$\Rightarrow$ $V=2\pi\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}\sin \varphi\mathrm d\varphi\int_{0}^{r\left( \varphi \right)}r^{2}\mathrm dr=\frac{2\pi}{3}\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}r^{3}\left( \varphi \right)\sin\varphi\mathrm d\varphi$
But the solution from the book says we can use the second theorem of Guldin to prove. For the infinitesimal area element, its centroid can be considered to be at the point $\left( \frac{2}{3}r\cos \varphi,\frac{2}{3}r\sin \varphi \right)$, and $\mathrm dA=\frac{1}{2}r^{2}\mathrm d\varphi$
$\Rightarrow$ $\mathrm dV=2\pi \frac{2}{3}r\sin \varphi \frac{1}{2}r^{2}\mathrm d\varphi$
$\Rightarrow$ $V=\frac{2\pi}{3}\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}r^{3}\left( \varphi \right)\sin\varphi\mathrm d\varphi$
So why the centroid of the infinitesimal area element can be considered to be at this point?

They're referring to the centroid of the entire sliver given by $0\le r\le r(\phi)$ with $\varphi\le\phi\le\varphi+d\varphi$, not to your infinitesimal area element for the double integral. Note that for this region, we have
$$\bar x \approx \frac1{\frac12r(\varphi)^2\,d\varphi} \int_{\varphi}^{\varphi+d\varphi}\int_0^{r(\phi)} (r\cos\phi)r\,dr\,d\phi \approx \frac{
\frac13r(\varphi)^3\cos\varphi d\varphi}{\frac12r(\varphi)^2\,d\varphi}=\frac23 r(\varphi)\cos\varphi,$$
and similarly for $\bar y$.
(Note that for such a sliver, we have $\bar r \approx \frac23 r(\varphi)$, rather than with a factor of $1/2$, because the mass is not evenly distributed in such a sector. There is more mass farther out than near the origin.)
